Comparing two closures for identity
I have an array of closures for filtering objects with array_reduce:
function test1(/* params */): bool { /* code returns true or false */ }
function test2(/* params */): bool { /* code returns true or false */ }
function test3(/* params */): bool { /* code returns true or false */ }
// ... many more

$closures = [ test1(...), test2(...), test3(...) ];

function filterObject(object $object): bool {
  return array_reduce(
    $closures(),
    fn(bool $carry, Closure $filter): bool => $carry && $filter($object),
    true
  );
}

function filterObjectArray(array $objects): array {
  return array_filter(
    $objects,
    fn(object $object): bool => filterObject($object)
  );
}

$result = filterObjectArray($contacts);

This works well. Now I need to filter the same data, but omit one of the closures, so basically I need this:
$closuresFiltered = [ test1(...), test3(...) ];   // test2(...) omitted

I tried to filter the closures array:
$closuresFiltered = array_filter(
  $closures,
  fn(Closure $closure): bool => $closure !== test2(...)   // always false
);

... but learned that one cannot compare a closure to itself to check for identity:
echo test1(...) === test1(...) ? 'true' : 'false';   // Will always return false

What I tried:
Reflection, but it becomes very quickly obvious that it is not possible with reflection.
I also tried spl_object_hash, but it returns the same hash for any closure whatever its parameters and return type are:
$hash1 = spl_object_hash(test1(...));
$hash2 = spl_object_hash(test2(...));
echo $hash1 === $hash2 ? 'true' : 'false';   // always true

The two work-arounds I have are:
– Use a descriptive key in the array of the closures and then filter by this key:
$closures = [
  'filterThis' => test1(...),
  'filterThat' => test2(...),
  'filterMore' => test3(...)
];

... which I don't like because literals are error prone. Of course an enum would help in that situation (maybe a string backed enum), but in the end it's just more code for little benefit.
– Serialize the closures (with Laraval's library or the Opis/closure library for example) and use them as the key:
$closures = [
  new SerializableClosure(test1(...)) => test1(...),
  new SerializableClosure(test2(...)) => test2(...),
  new SerializableClosure(test3(...)) => test3(...)
];

Again this adds more code – and dependencies otherwise not needed in my project – for little benefit.
Is there any way to check for two closure references pointing to the same closure.
Note that I'm aware that there are questions like How to compare two functions in PHP?, but they deal with equality – and not identity – of two function or closure references.

My assumption is that test1(...) creates a new closure, so test1(...) === test1(...) is literally two unique closures. This would be the same as new stdClass === new stdClass which would return false. To have the "same closure", you'd need to assign a reference to it such as: https://3v4l.org/egAiS

IMHO elegant workaround: use invokable objects instead of closures. Than you can test class of object.

@MichalHynčica That is correct. I forgot to mention that as third solution which I tried (it was my initial solution, but it also adds a lot of 'noise', and then I moved to 'descriptive keys').

I would have thought that when you build the array of closures is the best time to decide what to add. This stops any need to identify what to remove.

I'm not sure why === doesn't work, but == does. I'm not sure what kind of false positives this could produce.

@ChrisHaas I'm not sure that the first class callable syntax is different to a closure assigned to a variable, I don't think that it creates a new closure. It is just that the Closure class is special, it also cannot be subclassed, etc. You are right, one needs a reference. Which is what I do with the 'descriptive key' approach. An alternative to that would be a global constant with the same name as the function, like: const test1 = 'test1'; But then I have literals again, which I prefer to avoid.

@Barmar That is indeed true – and fascinating (thereby meaning: why does it work?). It seems to really return true only for the same function.

The closure contains a function property holding the function name, I assume it's comparing that. And you can't create distinct named functions with the same name. Note also that it does distinguish anonymous closures. var_dump((fn($a) => $a + 1) == (fn($a) => $a + 1)); says false.

@NigelRen The actual case contains a lot of small filter functions. It is for a predicate query system inspired by NSPredicate and NSPredicateEditor on macOS. There are so many combinations that I'd like to build them automatically. Simplified: I have 20 filter functions, I need to AND them, and then additionally filter with all of them minus the 1st, and all of them minus the 2nd, and all of them minus the 3rd, etc.

@Barmar Yes, I saw that closures carry the function name with them internally. I wish there was a someFunction::function syntax like with someClass::class.

Btw. Why do you insist on identity instead of equality? $closure != test2(...) should work fine if your closures are created from regular functions and not from anonymous functions.
